# Segmentation Fault 11 with C in Terminal

Tags: c, terminal, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a simple program in C, trying to teach myself the language for the first time and also learning to use my (Mac) Terminal for the first time.
However, I keep getting a segmentation fault error when I try to enter a variable (ssn) into scanf() to be saved. I changed the variable from an int to a long hoping to resolve the problem (which I looked up and thought had to do with memory availability/access) but to no avail.
I would really appreciate some guidance, thank you!
My code is below:

```
/* A short example program from cs449 C Programming Text */
/* Section 4.13 */
/* Exercise 4-1 */

/**********************************************************
*                                                         *
*     Write a program to print a name, SSN, and DOB       *
*                                                         *
**********************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[20];      /* an array of char used to hold a name */
    long ssn;           /* an integer for holding a 9 dig ssn */
    long dob;           /* an integer for holding a date of birth */

    /* for the name */
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    /* for the SSN */
    printf("Please enter your ssn: ");
    scanf("%ld", ssn);

    /* for the date of birth */
    printf("Please enter your date of birth:\n");
    printf("Ex. monthdayyear or 041293\n");
    scanf("%ld", dob);

    /* final print of user-entered information */
    printf("You are %s born on %d and your SSN is %d", name, dob, ssn); 

    /* remember to always return 0 at the end of a main funct! */
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for catching that mistake!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, go ahead and copy my answer to the comments :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks so much!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I was just joking, man, because you were saying _exactly_ what I said in my answer even in the same order :)

Comment: Rolled back. You must not edit the question rendering an existing answer useless!

Comment: @Olaf I have changed my question edits back to my original question

Comment: You did not just rollback (which I already did), but you edited. Ironically your edit made the code even worse, the original version was correct already at that place! Not sure why you edited anyway.

Comment: @Olaf I thought I was supposed to have the code exactly as I first presented it. The first time I edited it, I changed it to something closer to the correct answer. The second time I changed it back so that it was as I first entered it. Not sure what rollback is. Quite new to the site. Thanks.

Comment: Please see the FAQ and take the [tour] then. I rolled back to revision 1 which does show the correct format specifiers for `scanf`. Just see the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following:

```
scanf("%ld", &ssn);
```

And then

```
scanf("%ld", &dob);
```

This is because you want `scanf` to read the numbers *into* your variables, you want them *to be changed by this function*, so you give it a *pointer* to these variables.

---

Also, you'd better output the numbers properly, with `%ld` instead of `%d`:

```
printf("You are %s born on %ld and your SSN is %ld", name, dob, ssn);
```

Comment: thanks! do I need to do this for the string input as well? --> scanf("%s", name);

Comment: @Her, no, you don't, `scanf` already sees `name` as _a pointer_ to the first element of `name`.

Comment: @Her: since `name` is declared as an array, `name` is already a pointer to beginning of the array, so you don't need the `&`.  Arrays are funny in C and intimately tied up with pointers in odd ways like this.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: "since ... `name` is already a pointer to beginning of the array..." - **No!** It decays to such a pointer for most uses, including the usage here, but it **is** an array, not a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf: it depends on the context -- in this (and most) contexts, an identifier whose corresponding declaration has an array type *is* a pointer.  Saying it "decays" is just confisuing the issue -- there's no extra run-time overhead or conversion involved.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: You did not even mention there are cases it does not. That was my major issue with your comment. Remember this is read by beginners who typically will take this literally. They will not know the difference and just memorise "array is identical to pointer". You have enough reps to know the plethora of questions which just pop up just because of this missconception. Being precise and consistent does never confuse. It might, however, raise another question in the asker what "decays means, so just use "is converted to" (the standard never uses the term "decays").